# custom UITableViewCell change font when scroll in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` in which I have an `UILabel`.

Here is my code:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "PromoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? SchedaCompletaCellTVC // it's my custom tableview cell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = SchedaCompletaCellTVC(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default,reuseIdentifier:"PromoCell")
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString: company.name)
        cell!.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 17.0)

    case 1:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString: company.description)
    case 2:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Contatti"
        cell!.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)
    case 3:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Indirizzo:  \(String(htmlEncodedString: company.address)),\(String(htmlEncodedString: company.city)),\(String(htmlEncodedString: company.province)) "
    case 4:
        var telString:NSString = String(htmlEncodedString: company.phone)
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Tel: \(telString)"

    case 5:
        var email = String(htmlEncodedString: company.email)
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Email: \(email)"

    case 6:
        var sitoweb = String(htmlEncodedString: company.site)
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Sito: \(sitoweb)"

    case 7:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Fax: \(String(htmlEncodedString: company.fax))"
    default:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = ""

    }


    return cell!
}
```

When I scroll down, cells get wrong font and change every time.

Hope anybody can help! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "PromoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? SchedaCompletaCellTVC // it's my custom tableview cell

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = SchedaCompletaCellTVC(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default,reuseIdentifier:"PromoCell")
}
```

You are reusing the cell. And in some cell you are setting the font and in some other you are not doing any change in the font attribute.

```
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString: company.name)
        cell!.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 17.0)

    case 1:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = String(htmlEncodedString: company.description)
    case 2:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Contatti"
        cell!.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)
    case 3:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Indirizzo:  \(String(htmlEncodedString: company.address)),\(String(htmlEncodedString: company.city)),\(String(htmlEncodedString: company.province)) "
    case 4:
        var telString:NSString = String(htmlEncodedString: company.phone)
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Tel: \(telString)"

    case 5:
        var email = String(htmlEncodedString: company.email)
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Email: \(email)"

    case 6:
        var sitoweb = String(htmlEncodedString: company.site)
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Sito: \(sitoweb)"

    case 7:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = "Fax: \(String(htmlEncodedString: company.fax))"
    default:
        cell!.valueLabel.text = ""
}
```

In 3,4,5,6,7 you are not setting font. Set the desired font size in those cells it will work. :)